# Using tkinter I want to be able to get two inputs from the user using the same radiobuttons

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Using this list I want to be able to get two inputs. That will be stored in variables. Any suggestions?? Please help I am new to tkinter.

```
import tkinter as tk

class App():

    def __init__(self, master):

        self.master = master

        self.type_integration = None

        self.typeChoice = tk.StringVar()

        self.typeChoice.set(None) # This fixes the grayness of the radio buttons!

        self.typeFrame = tk.Frame(master)

        OPTIONS = [('Arsenal','Arsenal'),('Aston Villa','Aston Villa'),('Burnley','Burnley'),('Chelsea','Chelsea'),('Crystal Palace','Crystal Palace'),('Everton','Everton'),('Hull','Hull'),('Leicester','Leicester',),('Liverpool','Liverpool'),('Manchester City','Manchester City'),('Manchester United','Manchester United'),('Newcastle United','Newcastle United'),('Queens Park Rangers','Queens Park Rangers'),('Southampton','Southampton'),('Stoke','Stoke'),('Sunderland','Sunderland'),('Swansea','Swansea'),('Tottenham','Tottenham'),('West Bromwich Albion','West Bromwich Albion'), ('West Ham','West Ham')]

        for text, value in OPTIONS:

            tk.Radiobutton(self.typeFrame, text=text, variable=self.typeChoice, value=value).pack(anchor = 'w')

        tk.Button(self.typeFrame, text="Confirm Home Team", command=self.exit).pack(anchor = 'w')

        self.typeFrame.pack()

    def exit(self):

        self.type_integration = self.typeChoice.get()


        self.master.destroy()




    def getinput(self):

        return self.type_integration





master = tk.Tk()

app = App(master)

tk.mainloop()

home = app.getinput()
print(home)
```

Do I need to make another class?? Or can I reuse the code?? Help would be much appreciated. Am willing to listen to anything as I am not very good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RadioButton` is a Tkinter widget used to implement **one-of-many** selections.

You need to use [`CheckButton` widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/checkbutton.htm) instead to do what you want.

```
def __init__(self, master):
    ...
    self.variables = variables = []
    for text, value in OPTIONS:
        var = tk.StringVar()
        variables.append(var)
        tk.Checkbutton(self.typeFrame, text=text, variable=var,
                       onvalue=text, offvalue='').pack(anchor = 'w')
    ...

def exit(self):
    self.type_integration = ','.join(v.get() for v in self.variables if v.get())
    self.master.destroy()
```

**UPDATE**

To limit at most 2 selection:

```
def __init__(self, master):
    ...
    self.variables = []
    self.checkboxs = []
    for text, value in OPTIONS:
        var = tk.StringVar()
        cb = tk.Checkbutton(self.typeFrame, text=text, variable=var,
                            onvalue=text, offvalue='', command=self.limit2)
        cb.pack(anchor = 'w')
        self.variables.append(var)
        self.checkboxs.append(cb)
    ...

def limit2(self):
    if sum(bool(v.get()) for v in self.variables) >= 2:
        # Disable non-selected items to limit selection
        for cb, v in zip(self.checkboxs, self.variables):
            if not v.get():
                cb['state'] = 'disabled'
    else:
        for cb in self.checkboxs:
            cb['state'] = 'normal'
```

Comment: Is it possible to limit the number checked to 2??

Comment: @user12345678, `CheckButton` does not limit it. You should implement it yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much, where are the checkbuttons answered stored?

Comment: @user12345678, self.variables contains variables for checkbuttons.